# JFreechart Zoom with mouseWheelListener

Tags: jfreechart

I'am using a swing JFreechart component inside my RCP application. This JFreechart zooms properly with mouseWheel when run as a swing component. But after embedding it with RCP, this zoom with mouseWheel is not working. What could be the reason?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check [`isMouseWheelEnabled()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#isMouseWheelEnabled%28%29). Note that versions of the Java runtime older than 1.4 do not support mouse wheel events.